# One div per line when using `float: left`?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following HTML and CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/x7zr999s/

If the browser is small enough, it gives the desired result:

[image]

But if it's big enough, there are two or more items per line:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this without disabling `float: left` or enabling anything that breaks it? I want the posts to "wrap" around the original post like in the images.

Comment: What does the HTML and CSS look like?

Comment: @j08691 see the jsfiddle

Comment: @sdig fiddles are not supposed to serve as a reference for code. The reason you are not allowed to link to a fiddle without posting any code. The question should be answerable without the use of a fiddle.

Comment: Would you be so kind and let us know whether you found another solution (and answer your question on your own in this case - so we can also benefit from your investigations) or one of the given answers fitted your needs (and mark the adäquate answer as accepted in this case to honor the communities efforts)? :)

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears because you have a fix width on your `div`. In your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7zr999s/) you have given the `div`, a width of `100`, so when the screen widther, and because your div are all `floated` `left` they fill in the extra space and that is what happen to your case.

```
// this code is from the fiddle you create

<div class="reply" width=100 height=100>reply <a href="#">1</a></div>
```

There are some way to solve this. and the easy way is to wrap your `div` and put exact width you desire. so when the screen widther your floated `div` will remain to there same position.

This is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7zr999s/1/).

In the demo i put extra `div` before the end `tag` of `div wrapper` and have a `class` name `blocker` that help not to break your layout. if you can see in your style are class `blocker style` is `clear:both` this article explain about [Clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

You can insert you code into a wrapper and give it a maximum width:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
}
.op, .reply {
  float: left
}
.reply {
  min-width: 51%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="op"></div>
  <div class="reply"></div>
  <div class="reply"></div>
  <!-- ... more to go ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: That would work well, except that I'm going to need some of the replies to be more than twice as wide as others.

Comment: Why do you have to float you replies? It's like saying: FLOAT but pleas don't FLOAT!
If i get it right you have just exactly one element that hafe to float and this is the "original post".
Am i right?

Comment: My goal is for the replies to "wrap" the op like [this](https://i.imgur.com/PMq0oUz.png). `float: left` is the only way I can find to do that.

Comment: That makes it look all right, but it would be really nice if the replies could be short (~300px) or long (~1400px), with no 51% tricks.

Comment: edited the answer once again.
if you don't want to overthink your concept and stay with it you could access the elements with javasrcipt for example.
if you need advice for this just tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Set CSS attribute `max-width` to the parent div. It sets the maximum width that the parent can extend to. The default width is 100% of the window size. However max-width property restricts further extension of width after the specified maximum value.

Float left wraps child elements if the required parent's width is available. In your case you can restrict it by not allowing the parent's width to extend after a certain point so that the child divs wraps in the given space i.e. in 1 column (required).